# How to get value from database, MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have this follow system that works with two columns and where the first column id follows the second column id, the problem is that I am trying to do a followers page where it shows who is following that person and I need to get the username related to that id from the users table and that's where I can't do it

This doesn't echo anything

```
<?php include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php"); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Followers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $profileid=$_GET['profid'];
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT user_one FROM Follow WHERE user_two='$profileid'");
        $queryname = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row["user_one"];
            while($name= mysqli_fetch_array($queryname, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $name1 = $name["username"];
                echo $name1;
            }
        }
      ?>            
    </body>
</html>
```

I can get it to echo the ids of the persons who are following but when I put another while to get the username according to that id, it gives me nothing

Comment: You should use joins to achieve that. If you don't know what joins are, then you will have to learn it :-)

Comment: profid is the id of the person of the page being seen, and db_conx is the database conection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you to understand joins:

```
<?php include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php"); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Followers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $profileid=$_GET['profid'];
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT u.username as username FROM Follow as f JOIN users as u on u.id = f.user_one WHERE f.user_two=".(int)$profileid);
        While($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo $row['username'];
        }
      ?>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use joins instead of making two queries

**something like:**

```
SELECT user_one FROM Follow
LEFT JOIN users ON user.id = follow.user_id
WHERE follow.id='$profileid'
```

**AND** `$profileid` should not be in the sql like that. it should be:

```
WHERE follow.id=?
```

Comment: Thanks anyways dude, i will look joins up